# Unexpected MYSQL UNION and extractvalue behaviour

Tags: mysql

I was attempting an error-based sql injection when I discovered a weird behavior that I can't explain. Here is a simple example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '' union SELECT extractvalue(rand(),concat(0x3a,(SELECT 1)));
```

Output: ERROR 1105 (HY000): XPATH syntax error: ':1'

But...

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '' union SELECT extractvalue(rand(),concat(0x3a,(SELECT 1 FROM users)));
```

Output: ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Now the second result is expected, because my users table have 3 columns. The first example is the one I don't understand.

Tested on 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could tell from messing around with it, because you are using a subquery, the expression is being evaluated in a different order. If you do this:

```
SELECT some_col FROM users WHERE username = '' union SELECT extractvalue(rand(),concat(0x3a,(SELECT 1 FROM users LIMIT 1)));
```

Essentially resolving the "different number of columns" exception, I think you'll get the same error as the first line again. At least in my testing, that's what happened. I guess it has to do with when the subquery is evaluated, cause that has to happen before the extractvalue() call can be completed.

I'm also pretty sure mysql doesn't read "SELECT 1" as a subquery, but rather probably just discards the "SELECT" entirely.